# Cut Command Question - Column pulls other column if missing data

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have an example file on a Linux system:

```
Sally Smith
John Smith
Bill
Sam
```

When I run this command I get the first column:

```
$ cut -d " " -f1 test.txt
Sally
John
Bill
Sam
```

When I run this command I get the second column AND the rest of the first column:

```
$ cut -d " " -f2 test.txt                                        
Smith
Smith
Bill
Sam
```

How can I use `cut` to just get the 2 lines from the second column?

Answer (score 3):

Use `cut` with `-s` option:

```
$ cut -sd' ' -f2 infile
Smith
Smith
```

From the ['man cut'](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html):

> -s, --only-delimited
> do not print lines not containing delimiters

Comment: Ahhhh! That worked! I reread man and now I understand. Thanks so much! Problem solved.

Comment: @AnthonyB you are welcome! see also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).